# ExecutorService: how to increase performance

Tags: java, http, executorservice

I have a list which contain latitude and longitude values I just traverse this list fetching the lat and longitude and find the weather report for particular Lat and longitude  and update the weather report in dB but it takes around 75 sec for 100 times. How can I decrease this time?

```java
ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

HttpClient weatherClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
for(LatandlngList value:latandlngList)
{
   Double lat= value.getLat();
   Double lng= value.getLng();
   String URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng
             +"&appid="+appId;

Future<String>future=executor. Submit(() - >findWeatherReport(URL) ;
Updateweatherreport(future.get());


}

private String findWeatherReport(URL){
HttpGet weatherReq=new HttpGet(URL);
HttpResponse weatherresult=weatherClient.execute(weatherReq);
return weatherresult;
} 

Private String Updateweatherreport(weatherreport)
{
//code for update weather report in dB 
return "ok" ;
}
```

Comment: Your code is blocking due to the `future.get` so basically you are issuing 1 request at a time. Use a `CompletableFuture` and do a `thenAccept` put all of those in a collection pass that to the `CompletableFuture.allOf` method and then call `isDone` on the resulting future, call it periodically until it finishes.

Comment: Yea ... so you need to submit all of the requests before you "get" the results.  However, if you are using the free API you are rate-limited to 60 requests a minute anyway; see https://openweathermap.org/price

Comment: Even easier, just update the result in the future, no need for a `CompletableFuture` that way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you are doing now

```java
Future<String>future=executor. Submit(() - >findWeatherReport(URL) ;
Updateweatherreport(future.get());
```

Create a method that does both in 1 go and call that.

```java
private String findAndUpdateWeatherReport(String url) {
  String report = findWeatherReport(url);
  return Updateweatherreport(report);
}
```

Now in the calling code do

```java
executor.submit(() -> findAndUpdateWeatherReport(URL));
```

Then after the submits do the following

```java
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.awaitTermination(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {}
```

This will shutdown the executor and wait until all tasks have finished and then cleanup the executor.